# Switch between google sheet pages

Tags: node.js, google-sheets-api

I've made this script that can get data from the google API, but it only pulls from the main "sheet". My question is, how do I pull data from a separate "sheet"?
By sheet I'm talking about https://file.coffee/u/BsphXGdGQ.png

```js
function listMajors(auth) {
  const sheets = google.sheets({version: 'v4', auth});
  sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
    spreadsheetId: '1nQZqd8B2_Zb2IRT212SmcawV1qycRnot5Js0GfFZNxs',
    range: 'A:V',
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return console.log('The API returned an error: ' + err);
    const rows = res.data.values;
    if (rows.length){
        console.log('Mother Email, Father Email','Payment Status');
        for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            if (i>1){
                console.log(`${rows[i][11]}, ${rows[i][14]}`, `${rows[i][3]}`);
            }
        }

    } else {
      console.log('No data found.');
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the values from the sheets except for "Master" sheet which is the 1st tab using the method of spreadsheets.values.get in Sheets API.
- You want to achieve this using googleapis of Node.js.
- You have already been able to get values from Spreadsheet using Sheets API.

For this, how about this answer?

#### Modification points:

At the method of `spreadsheets.values.get` in Sheets API, `range` is the A1Notation. In your script, it's `range: 'A:V'`. In this case, the 1st tab in the Google Spreadsheet is used. When you want to retrieve the values from other sheet like "Payments" in the same Google Spreadsheet, please include the sheet name to the range as follows.

#### From:

```
range: 'A:V',
```

#### To:

```
range: "Payments!A:V",
```

and

```
range: "'Payments'!A:V",
```

#### Note:

- When you want to retrieve the values from the sheet in other Google Spreadsheet, please modify the spreadsheet ID and the range. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Method: spreadsheets.values.get](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets.values/get)
- [A1 notation](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/concepts#a1_notation)